# Rails associations loop issue when associations have variable number of records

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-6

Looking for best practises for multiple assoications where tables can have variable rows and variable user assoications. For example:

Two users (Tim and Mary) go on a shopping trip and visit many shops (Shop one, Shop two and Shop three). At Shop one Tim buys 1 item, Shop two Mary buys 3 items and Shop three Tim buys 1 item and Mary buys 1 item. How do I go about displaying this data in a table, linking the right user to the right purchased item and only showing data if it is present?

**Schema**

```
create_table “shopping_trip”, force: :cascade do |t|
  t.string “location”
  t.date “date”
end

create_table “users”, force: :cascade do |t|
  t.string “name”
end

create_table “shop_one”, force: :cascade do |t|
  t.integer "shopping_trip_id"
  t.integer "user_id"
  t.string “item_purchased”
  t.decimal “item_price”
end

create_table “shop_two”, force: :cascade do |t|
  t.integer "shopping_trip_id"
  t.integer "user_id"
  t.string “item_purchased”
  t.decimal “item_price”
end

create_table “shop_three”, force: :cascade do |t|
  t.integer "shopping_trip_id"
  t.integer "user_id"
  t.string “item_purchased”
  t.decimal “item_price”
end
```

**Model**

```
Class ShoppingTrip < ApplicationRecord
  belongs_to :user
  has_many :shop_ones, dependent: :destroy
  has_many :shop_twos, dependent: :destroy
  has_many :shop_threes, dependent: :destroy
  accepts_nested_attributes_for :shop_ones, allow_destroy: true
  accepts_nested_attributes_for :shop_twos, allow_destroy: true
  accepts_nested_attributes_for :shop_threes, allow_destroy: true
end
```

**Controller**

```
def index
  @shopping_trips = ShoppingTrip.left_joins(:shop_ones, :shop_twos, :shop_threes).select(“ shop_ones.*,  shop_twos.*,  shop_threes.*”)
end
```

**Display data as such**

[image]

The main issue I'm having is where associations are using the same call method for the same user:

For example it's only listing the first user present for all records:

```
<% @shopping_trips.each do |s| %>
  <%= s.try(:user).try(:name)
<% end %>
```

Comment: A shopping trip is something temporal. I wouldn't make it a model. I would make a model `Shop` with the different shops and their locations as a column. And another model `Item` which belongs to `Shop`. Then just a joint table (has many through) named `Purchase` between `Item` and `User`. Then you can find any sequence of purchase for any user, and access the item purchased and the shop too.

Comment: This is definitely a design flaw, maybe you should read up on database design to at least 3rd normal form http://www.gitta.info/LogicModelin/en/html/DataConsiten_Norm3NF.html